# Strings Not Matching

Tags: php

I am trying to match 2 strings. The first string is a value sent through a form:

```
<?php echo form_open('setup/index'); ?>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label style="font-size: 20px;">Event ID: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eventid" placeholder="Enter the ID for the Event">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="getevent" value="Search">
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

And the 2nd is a value returned from an API call:

```
{
EventID: "4697",
Title: "Copenhagen Marathon",
Location: "Chicago, IL",
Date: "31-12-2020 00:00:00",
Nation: "USA",
NationName: "United States",
NationCode: "US",
Sport: "1",
SportName: "Running",
Status: "1",
EventSplashTime: "0",
TrackerID: "D",
RCUUID: "52414345-434F-4E4E-4543-543034363937",
RCEmgPhone: "+4570265252",
RCEmgSMS: "+4525187952",
RCEmgAppHeader: "Contact Race Control",
RCEmgAppText: "NOTICE: This function is only for real emergencies. If you need urgent assistance use the call button.",
RCEmgPingURL: "default",
RCMode: "1",
RCAdvertiseInterval: "50",
RCAdvertisePower: "4",
RCEventAppIOSScheme: "something",
RCEventAppAndroidScheme: "something",
RCApplePriceTier: "0",
RCGooglePriceTier: "0"
}
```

The code I am using to retrieve the record is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://live.....");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response == FALSE) {
    die("cURL error " . curl_error($ch));
}

$responseObj = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

The value I am trying to match is the EventID in the Record with the eventid sent with the form.

I have tried:

```
1)

foreach($responseObj->Data->Records->Record as $record) {
    $temp = (string)$record->EventID;
    $sim = similar_text($temp, $eventid, $percent);
    if($sim === 4) {
        redirect("admin/index");
    } else {
        redirect("setup/error404");
    }
}

2)

foreach($responseObj->Data->Records->Record as $record) {
    $temp = (string)$record->EventID;
    if($temp == $eventid) {
        redirect("admin/index");
    } else {
        redirect("setup/error404");
    }
}

3)

foreach($responseObj->Data->Records->Record as $record) {
    $temp = (string)$record->EventID;
    if(strcmp($temp, $eventid) != 0) {
        redirect("setup/error404");
    } else {
        redirect("admin/index");
    }
}
```

I simply cannot get the strings to match even though I am 100% positive that a record with a matching EventID does exist. I have tried using strlen to make sure the strings are the same length as well as stripping any special characters from both strings, but still cannot get a match.

EDIT: Added var_dump

```
SimpleXMLElement (object) [Object ID #29][25 properties]
EventID: (string) "4697"
Title: (string) "Copenhagen Marathon"
Location: (string) "Chicago, IL"
Date: (string) "31-12-2020 00:00:00"
Nation: (string) "USA"
NationName: (string) "United States"
NationCode: (string) "US"
Sport: (string) "1"
SportName: (string) "Running"
Status: (string) "1"
EventSplashTime: (string) "0"
TrackerID: (string) "D"
RCUUID: (string) "52414345-434F-4E4E-4543-543034363937"
RCEmgPhone: (string) "+4570265252"
RCEmgSMS: (string) "+4525187952"
RCEmgAppHeader: (string) "Contact Race Control"
RCEmgAppText: (string) "NOTICE: This function is only for real emergencies. If you need urgent assistance use the call button."
RCEmgPingURL: (string) "default"
RCMode: (string) "1"
RCAdvertiseInterval: (string) "50"
RCAdvertisePower: (string) "4"
RCEventAppIOSScheme: (string) "something"
RCEventAppAndroidScheme: (string) "something"
RCApplePriceTier: (string) "0"
RCGooglePriceTier: (string) "0"

SimpleXMLElement (object) [Object ID #32][18 properties]
EventID: (string) "4836"
Title: (string) "Red Bull Ragnarok"
Location: (string) "Geilo"
Date: (string) "20-03-2020 00:00:00"
Nation: (string) "NOR"
NationName: (string) "Norway"
NationCode: (string) "NO"
Sport: (string) "100"
SportName: (string) "Other"
Status: (string) "1"
EventSplashTime: (string) "0"
TrackerID: (string) "R"
RCUUID: (string) "52414345-434F-4E4E-4543-543034383336"
RCMode: (string) "0"
RCAdvertiseInterval: (string) "50"
RCAdvertisePower: (string) "4"
RCApplePriceTier: (string) "0"
RCGooglePriceTier: (string) "0"

SimpleXMLElement (object) [Object ID #29][17 properties]
EventID: (string) "4747"
Title: (string) "Om Die Dam Ultra Marathon"
Location: (string) "Hartbeespoort"
Date: (string) "14-03-2020 00:00:00"
Nation: (string) "RSA"
NationName: (string) "South Africa"
NationCode: (string) "ZA"
Sport: (string) "1"
SportName: (string) "Running"
Status: (string) "1"
EventSplashTime: (string) "0"
RCUUID: (string) "52414345-434F-4E4E-4543-543034373437"
RCMode: (string) "0"
RCAdvertiseInterval: (string) "50"
RCAdvertisePower: (string) "4"
RCApplePriceTier: (string) "0"
RCGooglePriceTier: (string) "0"
```

I used the extension var_masterpiece in Chrome to try and neaten up the output.

Comment: Show `var_dump($responseObj->Data->Records->Record)`, two-three elements at least

Comment: The response from the API looks like JSON and you are trying to decode it using `simplexml_load_string()`

Comment: I have made checked and I do have type set to XML when making the API call.

Comment: Ok, if you'll comment `if else` and do a simple `echo $tmp;`, will you see your IDs? If so, then you can `trim()` your input and compare it after. I mean `if ($tmp == trim($eventid)) { ... }`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for trying to help. If I echo $temp, I can see the EventID's and if I try and trim I still face the same issue. There is still no match.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes input data comes with empty spaces and string `"test"` doesn't equal to `"   test "`.

Your `$temp` has a trimmed value, so, use `trim($eventid)` during `if statement` also:

```
if ($tmp == trim($eventid)) { ... }
```

Now `"test"` equal `trim("   test ")`